# JS OOP - structure in multiple files

Tags: javascript, oop

i'm pretty new in js oop and have following code so far:

```
    (function (ns) {

        ns.addSection = function (name, def) {
            ns[name] = new def();
        }

    }(this.PG_GuiHelper = this.PG_GuiHelper || {}));


/**
 * HOVERTIP
 *
 * shows submenu on click / hover
 */
PG_GuiHelper.addSection('hovertip',function(){

    var section = this;

    /**
     * init
     */
    section.init = function() {
        section.registerListener();
    }
```

now i have a second file with helpers for forms. also with the same ns closure like on this code. both works fine.

target:

***file ns.js***

```
(function (ns) {

    ns.addSection = function (name, def) {
        ns[name] = new def();
    }

}(this.PG_Library = this.PG_Library || {}));
```

and now to my question: how can i add a new "section" to my existing hovertip helper to get this call at least: PG_Library.guiHelper.hovertip.init();

the existing calls are now: PG_GuiHelper.hovertip.init(). i hope you understand what i mean.
1 ns function for all files. each file can have their own section with subsections. and all are handled with PG_Library.section.subsection.function().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
window.PG_Library.guiHelper = window.PG_GuiHelper;
```

In your case you add `PG_Library` and `PG_GuiHelper` to `window`, so this will work.

If you want to have a single global (which is a good idea :-)) you can use:

```
var PG = {};

PG.GuiHelper = {};

(function (ns) {

    ns.addSection = function (name, def) {
        ns[name] = new def();
    }

}(PG.GuiHelper));

/**
 * HOVERTIP
 *
 * shows submenu on click / hover
 */
PG.GuiHelper.addSection('hovertip', function() {

    var section = this;

    /**
     * init
     */
    section.init = function() {
        section.registerListener();
    }
});
```

And respectively: `PG.Library.guiHelper = PG.GuiHelper;`

Comment: thx! that works fine, but i don't like to add everthing to the window object and that i have to create the function and register it seperatly.

Comment: In this case don't use `this` because `this` is reference to `window`, in your case.

Comment: Check my edit to see how you can refactor to not create multiple globals.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the existing `PG_GuiHelper` as a new section to your `PG_Library`:

```
PG_Library.addSection("guiHelper", function() {
    return PG_GuiHelper;
});
```